# Doxygen and XML files

Tags: xml, doxygen

What I am trying to do is use Doxygen to view files in the project. Some of the files are XML. So s it possible to get Doxygen to display XML files? And if so, how does one do it.

Version 1.9.7
Tried adding it to the input list but at a dead end
What it to be able to display XML files (i.e. same ability to display C++ files)

Comment: Which version of doxygen? What did you try? What do you want to accomplish exactly? How does a typical XML file look like? Show a MWE.